# Wrong reference number for subfloat

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

I am trying to reference a subfigure in my text but it is numbered incorrectly.
Here is a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Two pictures side by side}
        \label{img:both}
        \subfloat[first picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:first}
        }
        \subfloat[second picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:second}
        }
    \end{figure}

    This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has a wrong reference number.
    But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome ot TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Nice post with a complete MWE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I'd say that it's a *very good* first post!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `subfig` package is strongly dependent on the knowledge of the caption position -- is it above or below the figure or table?

An except of the `subfig` package documentation:

> 3.1.5 The Caption Position Option
>
> The caption package ‘position’ option specifies whether the caption appears before or
>   after the figure or table. This can adjust the relative spacing used to separate the float
>   from the surrounding text. However, for the subfig package, it serves a more important
>   function. That is it determines if the sub-floats belong to or are associated with the last \caption command to be given, or the next one to be executed sometime in the
>   future. If you find that you sub-references do not agree with the top-level labels, than
>   you may need to specifically set the ‘position’. This is best done when loading the
>   caption package, but may be done at anytime with the \captionsetup command.

So usually this can be fixed using the correct `position` settings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

% Telling the subfig package the desired caption positions
\captionsetup[figure]{position=t}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Two pictures side by side}
        \label{img:both}
        \subfloat[first picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:first}
        }
        \subfloat[second picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:second}
        }
    \end{figure}

    This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has a wrong reference number.
    But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}
\end{document}
```

However, KOMA-Script is some kind of special here because it has its own options and commands for specifying the main caption position. The `caption`/`subfig` package respects (and supports) the KOMA-Script approach, making the code line `\captionsetup[figure]{position=t}` not only superfluous but without any effect. (See `caption` package documentation for details, section about "KOMA-Script".)

So with KOMA-Script classes, one need to use the options and/or commands offered by KOMA-Script instead, at least for the main caption, for example with "captions=figureheading":

```
\documentclass[captions=figureheading]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

% Telling the subfig package the desired caption position
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Two pictures side by side}
        \label{img:both}
        \subfloat[first picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:first}
        }
        \subfloat[second picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:second}
        }
    \end{figure}

    This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has a wrong reference number.
    But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}
\end{document}
```

And voilà the reference will be correct, even with KOMA-Script. (Please note that because of a bug in KOMA-Script the option "captions=figureheading" used to have no effect. This was fixed in version 3.11b of KOMA-Script. If you have to deal with older versions of KOMA-Script and updating is not an option, try using `\captionabove` instead of `\caption`.)

Comment: Thanks Axel, this is not only a MWE but the minimal working solution. I prefer it as it is easy to remember and kind of self-explanatory. To be clear, it works just with the `\captionabove` command.

Comment: The *bug* has vanished by now. Can you maybe add a little update? It leads to confusion http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=90947#p90947

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I informed Markus about the bug in KOMA-Script right after this answer, and he has fixed it within weeks. See: http://www.komascript.de/node/1671 (in German) Unfortunately I forgot to update my answer here afterwards, will do this right now.

Answer (score 5):

[`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) checks whether the caption is placed at the top of a figure or at the bottom. This is to allow for writing the appropriate "parent" counter *with* the subfloat counter, which might only be updated with the parent `\caption`. A global replacement strategy to avoid this comes with a patch from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{subfig,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{subfig,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\patchcmd{\sf@subfloat}% <cmd>
  {\maincaptiontopfalse}% <search>
  {\maincaptiontoptrue}% <replace>
  {}{}}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above (globally changing `\maincaptiontopfalse` to `\maincaptiontoptrue`) stems from the conditional "parent" counter increment contained within a subsidiary macro after calling `\subfloat` called `\sf@subfloat` (comments added):

```
\def\sf@subfloat{%
  \begingroup
    \@ifundefined{caption@setfloattype}%
      \caption@settype
      \caption@setfloattype
          \@captype
    \sf@ifpositiontop{% <------------ Check caption position
      \maincaptiontoptrue
    }{%
      \maincaptiontopfalse
    }%
    \caption@settype{subfloat}%
    \caption@settype{sub\@captype}%
    \let\sf@oldlabel=\label
    \let\label=\subfloat@label
    \ifmaincaptiontop\else
      \advance\@nameuse{c@\@captype}\@ne% <--- Step "parent" counter when \maincaptiontopfalse
    \fi
    \refstepcounter{sub\@captype}%
    \setcounter{sub\@captype @save}{\value{sub\@captype}}%
    \@ifnextchar [%  %] match left bracket
      {\sf@@subfloat}%
      {\sf@@subfloat[\@empty]}}
```

Here's a full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{subfig,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{subfig,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\patchcmd{\sf@subfloat}% <cmd>
  {\maincaptiontopfalse}% <search>
  {\maincaptiontoptrue}% <replace>
  {}{}}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Two pictures side by side}
  \label{img:both}
  \subfloat[first picture]{
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
    \label{img:first}
  } \qquad
  \subfloat[second picture]{
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
    \label{img:second}
  }
\end{figure}

This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has a wrong reference number.
But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but I prefer the solution of Axel below because it does not require an additional package. Thanks Werner.

Answer (score 4):

There's a weird behavior of `subfig` that seems to work correctly only if the main caption is *under* the subfloats.

I can offer a rather horrible fix if you really want to have your main caption above the subfloats:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Two pictures side by side}
\label{img:both}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}

\subfloat[first picture\label{img:first}]
  {%
   \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}%
  }
\qquad
\subfloat[second picture\label{img:second}]
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}

\stepcounter{figure}
\end{figure}

This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has the correct reference number.
But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}
\end{document}
```

The label to the subfloats are best placed inside the argument to `\subfloat`.

Be careful with the spurious spaces in the mandatory argument to `\subfloat`; I've used two possible ways of inputting it that cure them. (Indentation is optional, I prefer not to indent the contents of "first level" environments.)

[image]

Comment: No, this is not a weird behavior of `subfig`, it's a well documented behavior instead.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I beg to differ; if it's documented, it's hard to find where and the manual references `position=top`, so one expects this works.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's hard to find. But IMHO that's a generic problem with package documentations: If they are documenting not enough, the documentation is short, but important facts are missing. If they are documenting too much, it may be hard to find the desired information, especially since LaTeX package authors are some kind of "code hackers" and not professional documenters. (And writing well-arranged but complete documentation is far from being an easy task.)

Comment: (What is missing here is a hint about the KOMA-Script stuff within the `subfig` documentation of the `position=` option. BUT: It has clear hints about reading the `caption` package documentation additionally, and the documentation about `position=` there has a clear hint (with an info mark) about KOMA-Script.)

Comment: Tinkering with the counters is not the way to go i think. I prefer to use implemented features.

Answer (score 1):

Move the main `label` and `\caption` to the end of the figure environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat[first picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:first}
        }
        \subfloat[second picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:second}
        }
        \caption{Two pictures side by side}
        \label{img:both}
    \end{figure}

    This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has a wrong reference number.
    But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the suggestion but I prefer the caption on top of the figures because I use the hyperref package. When I click on the link which a reference produces my pdf viewer moves to the figure in a way that aligns the caption at the top. Therefore i have to scroll up to this the figure.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the caption and the label for the `figure` environment to the bottom and that solved the problem for me. Below is my MWE with the output.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat[first picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:first}
        }
        \subfloat[second picture]{
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
            \label{img:second}
        }
        \caption{Two pictures side by side}
        \label{img:both}
    \end{figure}

    This example shows that figure \ref{img:second} has a wrong reference number.
    But the complete float is referenced correctly: \ref{img:both}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Umar, its working indeed but I like my caption above the figure. See my comment on the post ahead for more infos.