# wrong numbering for subcaption in scrbook

Tags: numbering, subcaption, scrbook

When using the `scrbook` document class in combination with the `subcaption`  package, the numbering of subfigures seems broken. Consider:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{%
  format=hang,%
  font=small,%
  labelfont={sf,bf},%
  aboveskip=0.2\normalbaselineskip,%
  position=top
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Black}
  \label{fig1}
  \centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{More figures}
  \label{fig2}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Blue}
    \label{fig2a}
    \color{red}\rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Green}
    \label{fig2b}
    \color{green}\rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Blue}
    \label{fig2c}
    \color{blue}\rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig1} shows a black box. Figure \ref{fig2} shows colored
boxes, where Figure \ref{fig2a} shows a red box, Figure \ref{fig2b}
shows a green box, and Figure \ref{fig2c} shows a blue box.
\end{document}
```

This results in the following display: 
[image: broken]

Clearly, the figure numbering in the text references is off by one for the subfigures. Instead, if I change the document class to `article`, it looks fine:

[image: fixed]

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using KOMA-Script the default setting is "captions are below figures". To change this, specify `captions=figureheading`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[captions=figureheading]{scrbook}
```

What effect does this option have for KOMA-Script?

KOMA-Script needs this option to give you the correct vertical spacing between caption and figure.

What effect does this option have for the subcaption package?

The `subcaption` package needs to know when a figure starts and when a figure ends. Since one can place multiple captions inside one figure environment, "when a figure+caption starts" is not equal `\begin{figure}` and "when a figure+caption ends" is not equal `\end{figure}`.

See also:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115632/2574 (Same problem, but with tables)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98331/2574 (Same problem, but using `subfig` package)