# The subcaption package counts incorrectly under KOMA script

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, koma-script, subfloats, subcaption

I have a figure with two subfigures, each with its own caption. When I refer to the figure the numbering is correct, but when I refer to a subfigure the figure number is one more than it should be. If I change the document class to `article` the error does not appear. How to fix the numbering when referencing under KOMA script?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Two photos} \label{fig:photos}
        \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \caption{People on a square}
      \label{fig:square}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/square.jpg}
                {\footnotesize By Lina Kivaka and available at
                    \url{https://www.pexels.com/photo/people-walking-near-white-building-3989821/}
                \par}
  \end{subfigure}
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \caption{Cabin over a lake}
      \label{fig:cabin}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/cabin.jpg}
                {\footnotesize By Lucas Craig and available at
                    \url{https://www.pexels.com/photo/cabin-on-green-grass-field-near-lake-under-white-clouds-3689772/}
                \par}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

When I refer to panel~\subref{fig:square} of Figure~\ref{fig:photos} it is displayed as
Figure~\ref{fig:square}. Similarly panel~\subref{fig:cabin} is displayed as Figure~\ref{fig:cabin}.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE: subfigures]

Comment: `\documentclass[captions=figureheading]{scrartcl}` should work

Comment: See also: [wrong numbering for subcaption in scrbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338642/134144)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes

Comment: @leandriis It worked. Thank you!