# subfigure sets figure counter wrong

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

If I go into a `figure` environment, set the `\caption` first and then the `subfigures`, the *figure-counter* is increased by two.
If i put the `subfigures` first and the `\caption` below, it is correctly increased by one.

It seems like `\caption` checks if the *figure-counter* was increased in the own environment, for `subfigure` it seems to not be that way.

As a workaround I found`\addtocounter{figure}{-1}`.

Is there an option to fix it with an optional argument?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{htbp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Nr.\ of figures (in figure): \arabic{figure}. \\
    Start a \texttt{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      Nr.\ of figures (in subfigure): \arabic{figure}.
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}.}
  \end{figure}

  Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}. \\
  Counter \texttt{figure} increased by one.

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}.}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      Nr.\ of figures (in subfigure): \arabic{figure}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}

  Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}. \\
  Counter \texttt{figure} increased by \textbf{two!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338685/113546
Use `\documentclass[captions=figureheading]{scrartcl}`

Comment: Thanks very much. That solved it, had it for the tables, but not for the figures, smh.
If you can add it as an answer, i can solve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem about the way `scrartcl`  deals with captions. See [tex.stackexchange.com/a/338685/113546](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338685/113546). Use `\documentclass[captions=figureheading]{scrartcl}`.

```
\documentclass[captions=figureheading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{htbp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Nr.\ of figures (in figure): \arabic{figure}. \\
    Start a \texttt{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      Nr.\ of figures (in subfigure): \arabic{figure}.
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}.}
  \end{figure}

  Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}. \\
  Counter \texttt{figure} increased by one.

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}.}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      Nr.\ of figures (in subfigure): \arabic{figure}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}

  Nr.\ of figures: \arabic{figure}. \\
  Counter \texttt{figure} increased by \textbf{two!}
\end{document}
```

[image]